# Pause unpause while keeping the same values of variables?

Tags: android, c++, sdl-2

I am learning to make games using **SDL** and **C++**.

I use **time-based movement** not frame rate.
My player moves right/left and when I press space it changes direction.

Now if I pause the game by

- minimizing it on windows
- pressing the HOME button on my Phone (Android)
- or close the screen also on phone

the timer doesn't pause. 
( **SDL_GetTicks()** doesn't stop) and my player continues to move.

When the player touches the "walls" or "enemies" they die and the game is over. 
This happens every time when I pause the game.

- How can I solve this problem?
- How can my variables ( ex. : positions of different sprites/objects) maintain their values when I pause the game for X seconds and then unpause it later?

Please leave as much of a detailed explanation as you can and I would be really appreciative.

Comment: Good work getting first question out - but don't worry about using Bold - try use more bullet lists and space to make it clearer.  Hope it gets answered!

Comment: Thanks for the tip and editing. I will try to do it like this next time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just stop your timers when the game is paused and start them again (possibly taken the paused time into account) when you are unpaused? Or you may have meant to detect when the game is paused and just set a flag that "everything is on hold".
There are many ways to solve this, none of them really difficult.
Try a few approaches, then let us know what you have tried and your results.
The question needs more detail...

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between using *time-based* (never heard this term) movement or directly frame rate is simple: everything is the same but with *time-based* you take into account the time elapsed from previous frame (which basically means that you have a void `logic(float dt)` instead that `logic(void)`)

So everything won't stop also with a fixed time step, as long as the loop keeps running.

The simplest way to do it is just to skip the main loop logic if the application has been resigned and reset the time of the last frame as soon as it resumes. Something like:

```
while (running) {
  if (!isResigned) {
    uint32_t timeElapsed = SDL_GetTicks();
    uint32_t timeDelta = timeElapsed - timeStart;
    logic(timeDelta);
    timeStart = timeElapsed;
  }
}

void applicationResumed() {
  timeStart = SDL_GetTicks();
  isResigned = false;
}

void applicationResigned() {
  isResigned = true;
}
```

This prevents the fact that resuming after some time will consider all the time spent resigned as time to be fed to the logic, while this shouldn't happen.

Comment: I would consider adding a small time delay on an else statement to the loop so it (the loop) doesn't continuously run through that if check.  You won't want it to be too large because you don't want to wait 10 seconds for the game to come back if the player happens to hit resume right at the start of the sleep, but enough that you're not chewing up extra clock cycles (and power) you don't need to be.

Comment: I expect the real main loop to be already limited by the desired fps amount, so an SDL_Delay should be already present to keep the fps to the desired value.

Comment: Shows how much I know about SDL.  Thanks for explaining why the wait wasn't necessary.

Comment: Here it is explained how you should limit your fps: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson14/, basically this principle applies to the OP situation too, the only difference is that the logic shouldn't be called if the application is resigned and the time point should be reset.

Comment: Thanks,Jack! That would probably work...if I just knew how to restore the window back...

Comment: Jack / @Tuffwer .. any idea why SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESTORED doesn't work?